# Can't find element by index using XPath

Tags: html, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I write XPath in Console to find icon element `$x("//mat-icon")`.
Then I get list of elements:

```
0: <mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate mat…-color ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-cvb-c17="" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="start" role="img">
1: <mat-icon class="mat-icon notranslate mat…-color ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-cvb-c17="" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="start" role="img">
```

and I want to pick the first one so I write index `$x("//mat-icon[1]")` but it doesn't work. However, if I write `$x("//mat-icon")[1]` it works, but when I write it in IDE error message appears:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-icon")[0]).click();
```

Comment: You don't need to specify an index. `.findElement()` always returns on the first element found.

Comment: @JeffC: True, but there's an underlying XPath gotcha in play here too:  OP should use `(//mat-icon)[1]` to select the first `mat-icon` in the document.  `//mat-icon[1]` means *select the `mat-icon` elements that are the first child of its parent*, which may well be different than the first `mat-icon` in the document.  See duplicate link for details.

Comment: There are some situations where issue is not with locators, but element is hidden(not interact-able), can you please look at the css style values of current node as well as parent nodes. You may find the reason why you cant interact with it. You may have to use trick of updating css value to interact with element.

Comment: @kjhughes Agreed but... OP said `I want to pick the first one` then tried two different ways. 1. `$x("//mat-icon[1]")` which didn't work so it's not the first child of its parent (as you explained). He then tried 2. `$x("//mat-icon")[1]` which just means get the first in the document and it did work. So, in the case presented in this question `.findElement()` would work just fine... no index, nothing complicated needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick the first `<<mat-icon>` element you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `findElements()`, [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and `get()`:

  ```
  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("mat-icon")).get(0).click();
  ```
- Using `findElements()`, [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and `get()`:

  ```
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-icon")).get(0).click();
  ```
- Using `findElements()`, [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and *index*:

  ```
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-icon")).get(0).click();
  ```

Comment: I see no reason for a downvote here; I'll counter it with an up.  Note, though, that the basis for OP's misunderstanding is the common mistake regarding the difference between `//mat-icon[1]` and `(//mat-icon)[1]`.  See duplicate link for further details.

Comment: @DebanjanB `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-icon"))[0].click()` does't work. There is error "Array type expected"

Comment: @Yamis How about the first option?

Comment: @DebanjanB First option work, but i don't use cssSelectors to find elements. I would say that i don't know cssSelector commands:)

Comment: @Yamis Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following:

```
driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//mat-icon")).get(0).click();
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: This is one way to achieve the result (+1).  Note, though, that the basis for OP's misunderstanding is the common mistake regarding the difference between `//mat-icon[1]` and `(//mat-icon)[1]`.  See duplicate link for further details.

Comment: @kjhughes, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-icon"))[0].click()` does not work. There is error "Array type expected"

Comment: @Yamis, I have updated my answer. Now it should work. I forgot that it's Java :)